# Why does function not return from while loop

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, data-structures

I'm solving the LeetCode question [33. Search in Rotated Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array/description/):

> There is an integer array `nums` sorted in ascending order (with **distinct** values).
>
> Prior to being passed to your function, `nums` is **possibly rotated** at an unknown pivot index `k` (`1 <= k < nums.length`) such that the resulting array is `[nums[k], nums[k+1], ..., nums[n-1], nums[0], nums[1], ..., nums[k-1]]` (**0-indexed**). For example, `[0,1,2,4,5,6,7]` might be rotated at pivot index `3` and become `[4,5,6,7,0,1,2]`.
>
> Given the array `nums` **after** the possible rotation and an integer `target`, return *the index of* `target` *if it is in* `nums`*, or* `-1` *if it is not in* `nums`.
>
> You must write an algorithm with `O(log n)` runtime complexity.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> **Input:** `nums = [4,5,6,7,0,1,2], target = 0`
> **Output:** `4`

Below is my code:

```
class Solution {
    fun search(nums: IntArray, target: Int): Int {
        if (nums.size == 0) return -1

        var low = 0
        var high = nums.size - 1
        var mid = 0

        //determine where the point pivot index is
        while (low < high) {
            mid = low + ((high - low) / 2)

            if (nums[low] > nums[high]) {
                low = mid
            } else {
                high = mid
            }
        }

        //determine if we need to look in left part or right part of the array
        if (target >= nums[0] && target <= nums[mid - 1]) {
            low = 0
            high = mid-1
        } else {
            low = mid
            high = nums.size-1
        }

        //searching the correct part of the array for the target number
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = low + ((high - low) / 2)
            if (nums[mid] == target) {
                println("LALALALA") //we see this log but loop keeps looping
                return mid
            }
            
            if (target < nums[mid]) {
                high = mid - 1
            } else {
                low = mid
            }
        }

        return -1
    }
}
```

The log before the return statement gets executed, but the loop keeps going. I don't understand why it's behaving this way. This may not be the correct solution to the problem, but why the return call does not exit the function?

Comment: How are you determining that the loop keeps looping? It’s impossible unless you called this function multiple times.

Comment: Doesn't terminate when low == high and nums[low] > target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues:

- Be aware that multiple tests are run, and so if the process seems to hang in an infinite loop just after seeing the output "LALALALA", it doesn't mean that the `return` didn't execute, but that the **next** run of your function got into an infinite loop. So your question in the subject is a misunderstanding: the function **does** return from the while loop.
- `nums[low] > nums[high]` is not the correct comparison. You need to involve `mid` in this comparison. So `nums[mid] > nums[high]` would be right.
- `low = mid` is an assignment that might not change `low`, as both might already be equal (this happens when `low == high - 1`. Yet the goal is to narrow down the window of the binary search, as otherwise you risk to loop forever. So do `low = mid + 1` -- also in the final binary search loop.
- With the above change, `mid` is no longer reliable for knowing the pivot index after the loop has ended. We can be sure however that `low==high` after the loop, and that this index represents the index that has the *least* value in the `nums` array. So use `low` or `high` instead of `mid` to get the pivot index. This means that `high = mid-1` can become `high--`, and the assignment `low = mid` can be dropped entirely.
- `target <= nums[mid - 1]` is not a safe expression as `mid` (or after the above change, `high`) might be zero. But actually this condition is not needed at all. Instead you could avoid executing the whole first part of the algorithm when the input array is not rotated, avoiding to treat this boundary case here.

Here is a correction of your code:

```
class Solution {
    fun search(nums: IntArray, target: Int): Int {
        if (nums.size == 0) return -1

        var low = 0
        var high = nums.size - 1
        var mid = 0

        if (nums[low] > nums[high]) { // Is array rotated?
            while (low < high) {
                mid = low + ((high - low) / 2)
                if (nums[mid] > nums[high]) { // [mid]
                    low = mid + 1 // add one
                } else {
                    high = mid
                }
            }
            if (target >= nums[0]) { // Removed second condition -- not needed
                // Pivotindex is at low==high!
                high--
                low = 0
            } else {
                high = nums.size-1
            }
        }

        while (low <= high) {
            mid = low + ((high - low) / 2)
            if (nums[mid] == target) {
                return mid
            }
            
            if (target < nums[mid]) {
                high = mid - 1
            } else {
                low = mid + 1 // add one
            }
        }

        return -1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to right this. I study everyday in hopes to be as good as you. You're a legend!